# Java arrays to insert values during runtime and size of the array is not constant

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How do I insert values in array whose size may change and I should get the values dynamically and I should do the same with another array.
The size of the array may range From 1 to 100. I should compare the values in both the arrays and display the odd man out.
Example
With lists `x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5]` and `y = [5, 2, 5, 13]`, the function `answer(x, y)` would return `6` because the list `x` contains the integer `6` and the list `y` doesn't.
Given the lists `x = [14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1]` and `y = [2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50]`, the function `answer(x, y)` would return `-4` because the list `y` contains the integer `-4` and the list `x` doesn't

```
class ArrayLi
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
                    throws IOException
    {
        int n=99,ins,i,j;
        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>(n)
        // Appending the new element at the end of the list
        //for(int var : arrli)
        for (i=1;i<n; i++)
            x.add(i);

        // Printing elements
        System.out.println(x);

        // Remove element at index 3
        for (j=1;j<n; j++)
        y.add(j);

        // Displaying ArrayList after deletion
        System.out.println(y);

        // Printing elements one by one
        for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
            System.out.print(x.get(i)+" ");
         for(int i=1;i<x.length;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<y.length;j++){
                if(x[i]==y[j]){
                    System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can do it manually, but the easy way is to use an `ArrayList` instead, because that's exactly what it does.

Comment: you can implement such code to solve this problem but already it is implemented by Java Collections API

Comment: The Javadoc in your example doesn't match what the does - at least not for the part where you claim to delete an element, but in fact you're adding elements to list `y`

Comment: I need to add elements manually not delete it. My code inserts elements into array from 1 to 100. I want to know how to enter it manually without specifying the size of array.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you *really* need to use arrays and/or do everything manually there is an easy way using Java 8's new API:

```
private static List<Integer> answer(List<Integer> x, List<Integer> y) {
    return Stream.concat(x.stream(), y.stream())
            .filter(i -> !x.contains(i) || !y.contains(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> x1 = Arrays.asList(13, 5, 6, 2, 5);
    List<Integer> y1 = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 5, 13);

    List<Integer> x2 = Arrays.asList(14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1);
    List<Integer> y2 = Arrays.asList(2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50);

    System.out.println(answer(x1, y1));
    System.out.println(answer(x2, y2));
}
```

Prints:

```
[6]
[-4]
```

Comment: how do i do this when i have to insert the array values manually? if i am using a for loop? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A pretty easy way would be to turn your arrays into `List`s.

You could do the following:

```
List<Integer> xList = Arrays.asList(x);
List<Integer> yList = Arrays.asList(y);
```

Then, if the original x array is larger, do `xSet.removeAll(ySet)`, or vice versa `ySet.removeAll(xSet)`.